# How to put the jquery validator on my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

This is my error:

> SyntaxError: missing } after property list

and here is my code:

```
 <script>
$(function(){
    $("#miForm").validate({
        rules: {
            hola: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    messages: {
            hola: {
                lettersonly: "Escribe sólo letras"      
            }
        }
    });
 });
 </script>
```

I have already called the `jquery.validate.js` , `jquery-1.11.3.min.js`, `additional-methods.js` and `messages_es.js`

Probably is missing something? plz help!

[picture of all my errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BJtF.png)

Comment: missing comma after rules? right before messages.

Comment: This is why consistent indentation matters ;-) It makes spotting these sort of problems much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma after rules, before messages.

```
$(function(){
    $("#miForm").validate({
        rules: {
            hola: {
                required: true
            }
        }, // <<-- right here
        messages: {
            hola: {
                lettersonly: "Escribe sólo letras"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
new error, what could be?

Comment: jquery needs to run before you run anything else `<script src=jquery...>` then `<script src=mystuff...>`